# Need to select a group of numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql

In mysql I have a table called employees and each have an id, there are 29 of them. Is there a way to select 13-25? (sorry this is my first post on here)

Comment: It would be beneficial if you could have given an SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Do you want to select the employees whose id are between 13 and 25 or do you want to select the 13th to 25th employees? Are the ids unique among the employees? Or do you mean you want to select 13 minus 25? Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

For sure, you can try with this one.

SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id > 12 AND id < 26;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `employees`
     WHERE `id` > 12
     AND   `id` < 26;
```

Alternatively, you can also do:

```
SELECT * FROM `employees`
     WHERE `id` >= 13
     AND   `id` <= 25;
```

Assuming that the `id` is of an integer type.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
   WHERE column_name >=13
   AND   column_name <=25
   GROUP BY column_name ASC;
```

Or

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name
   WHERE column_name 
   BETWEEN 13 AND 25;
```

Also checkout http://www.w3schools.com/ for more help with SQL

For MYSQL checkout https://www.tutorialspoint.com//mysql/index.htm